# std::bind equivalent in C# or VB.NET

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, .net-4.0, stdbind

I am in the process of refactoring "synchronous" code (i.e. uses Windows events to wait until some other thread finished doing something) to "asynchronous" code (using delegates to implement a callback mechanism).

In the sync code, I sometimes have local variables that I need to use after the wait is over. When code like that goes async, those local variables are lost (the callback handler can't access them). I can store them as class attributes, but it feels wasteful.

In C++, I use `std::bind` to work around this. I just add as many parameters as local variables needed to the callback handler, and bind them when I call the async method. For example, let's say that the async method callback receives an object of type `CallbackParam` and the caller uses two local variables of type `LocalA` and `LocalB`.

```
void AsyncClass::MethodWhichCallsAsyncMethod(){
    LocalA localVarA;
    LocalB localVarB;
    // OnAsyncMethodDone will need localVarA and localVarB, so we bind them
    AsyncMethod( std::bind( &AsyncClass::OnAsyncMethodDone, this, std::placeholders::_1, localVarA, localVarB ) );
}

void AsynClass::AsyncMethod( std::function<void(CallbackParam)> callback ){
    CallbackParam result;
    //Compute result...
    if( callback )
        callback( result );
}

void AsyncClass::OnAsyncMethodDone( CallbackParam p, LocalA a, LocalB b ){
   //Do whatever needs to be done
}
```

Is there some sort of equivalent to this in C# and VB.NET? Using delegates or something else?

**UPDATE**: For completeness' sake, here is the C# equivalent of my example based on @lasseespeholt's answer:

```
using System;

public class AsyncClass {

        public void MethodWhichCallsAsyncMethod() {
            var a = new LocalA();
            var b = new LocalB();
            //Anonymous callback handler (equivalent to AsyncClass::OnAsyncMethodDone)
            Action<CallbackParam> callback = result => {
                //Do what needs to be done; result, a and b can be accessed
            };
            AsyncMethod( callback );
        }

        private void AsyncMethod( Action<CallbackParam> callback ) {
            var result = new CallbackParam();
            //Compute result...
            if( callback != null )
                callback( result );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: This should almost certainly not be used. Use the async/await keywords in C#**

You can exploit closures like the following:

```
void MethodWhichCallsAsyncMethod()
{
    int foo = 1;

    AsyncCallback callback = result =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo); // Access to foo
    };

    AsyncMethod(callback);
}

void AsyncMethod(AsyncCallback callback)
{
    IAsyncResult result = null; // Compute result
    callback(result);
}
```

The compiler generates a class which contains "foo" so you don't save anything with this approach, but it's clean.

Comment: Looks nice; I was reluctant to add state to my class, but if the compiler does it I don't mind :P Can this be done in VB.NET as well? (we're talking .NET 4.0)

Comment: @dario_ramos I don't use VB.Net myself but yes. C# and VB.Net share most features. This page should help you using lambdas in VB.Net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx